# SQL Modeling / Query Question

Tags: sql, mysql, database-design

I currently have this database structure:

[image]

One entry can have multiple items of the type "file", "text" and "url".

Everyone of these items has exactly one corresponding item in either the texts, urls or files table - where data is stored.

I need a query to efficiently select an entry with all its corresponding items and their data.

So my first approach was someting like

```
SELECT * FROM entries LEFT JOIN entries_items LEFT JOIN texts LEFT JOIN urls LEFT JOIN files
```

and then loop through it and do the post processing in my application.

But the thing is that its very unlikely that multiple items of different types exist. Its even a rare case that more then one item exists per entry. And  in most cases it will be a file. But I need It anways...

So not to scan all 3 tables for eveyr item I thought I could do something like case/switch and scan the corresponding table based on the value of "type" in entries_items.

But I couldn't get it working.

I also thought about making the case/switch logic in the application, but then I would have multiple queries which would probabably be slower as the mysql server will be external.

I can also change the structure if you have a better approach!

I also having all the fields of "texts", "urls" and "files" in side the table entries_items, as its only a 1:1 relation and just have everything that is not needed null.
What would be the pros/cons of that? I think it needs more storage space and i cant do my cosntraints as i have them now. Everything needs also to be null...

Well I am open to all sorts of ideas. The application is not written yet, so I can basically change whatever I like.

Comment: I think this question goes way beyond the bounds of what you've outlined here.  For instance, you mentioned not wanting to scan every table.  Is that a comparison to table seeks?  How many rows does the entries table have?  How many calls would you make if you asked for one item at a time.  There are so many factors at work here, I don't think you'll get a simple answer that has any merit. (no offense to the selected answerer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three different entity types (URL, TEXT, FILE) being linked to the primary ENTRIES table via the intermediary table ENTRIES_ITEMS, and you are violating normal form with this "conditional join" approach. Given your structure, it is impossible to declare a foreign key constraint on ENTRIES_ITEMS.id because the id column could reference the URLS, the TEXTS, or the FILES table. To normalize the ENTRIES_ITEMS table you would have to add three separate fields, urlid, textid, and fileid and allow them to be nullable, and then you could join each of the three entities tables to the ENTRIES table via your linking table.  The approach you are taking is very commonly found in legacy databases that were not SQL92-compliant, where the values were grabbed from the entities tables programmatically/procedurally rather than declaratively using SQL selects.

Answer (score 1):

I would first consider adding a column to your "entries_items" table that contains an XML representation of texts, urls, and files.  I can't speak for MySQL, but SQL Server has fantastic facilities for handling XML.  I bet MySQL does too.

If not a state-of-the-art technique like that, then I would consider going retro and just having one items table with many nulls, as you already considered.

Comment: wow, definately gotta check that out! altough i'd prefer a more "classic sql" solution.

Answer (score 1):

This may get you started, but wil not resolve hierarchical structure (parent_id) of `entries` and `entries_items`.

```
select *
from entries       as e
join entries_items as i on i.entry_id = e.id
left join texts    as t on t.item_id  = i.id and i.type = 'text'
left join urls     as u on u.item_id  = i.id and i.type = 'url'
left join files    as f on f.file_id  = i.id and i.type = 'file'
;
```

If considering the model cleanup, this may be a starting point.

[image]

Comment: looks to me like this is what i have now, but thanks for the join conditions ;)